# How do i program my current program to input a command into another console in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

After creating a process (addaccount.exe) using my current process (run.exe), how do i program run.exe to input a command or pass information directly to addaccount.exe?

Edit:
So, if i have

STARTUPINFO si;
ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
si.hStdInput = //What do i put here?

Comment: I removed "C/C++" from your title, as you only use the C++ tag. Note that C is not the same as C++, and that there is no language called "C/C++".

Answer (score 1):

If you're using [`CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WIN32 function to create the new process, then you can set the standard input and output file handles of the new process. See the [`STARTUPINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686331%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, especially the three file handles at the end of that structure.

Comment: @Deckdyl Use your favorite search engine, there are plenty of examples and tutorials available, not only on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/) or here on SO, but all over.

Answer (score 0):

You can find a complete example here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)